# Htmlagilitypack show node #text instead of span

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have the following html markup :

```
        <div>
            <span id="391d0e73-d491-4e55-9ccb-b74c6923e070">This is a text
                element</span>
        </div>
```

Now if i save this div node in an `HtmlNode` object and after that when i access node's `FirstChild` then instead of giving `span node as FirstChild` it gives the node `NAME: "#text"` which is not present in the markup. Can please anybody help me out with this issue ?

Comment: no it does'nt contain `This is a text element`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-core.html#ID-1950641247), nodes include elements, text, comments etc, e.g. in your document, the `div` can have 2 `text` children:

```
<div>
    text(1) Some text could be here
    <span id="391d0e73-d491-4e55-9ccb-b74c6923e070">This is a text
        element</span>
    text(2) More text could be here
</div>
```

You need to specify that you want the `span` child element on your `HtmlNode`, e.g.

```
divNode.SelectSingleNode("span")
```